# Wake on Lan in Sleep/Hybernate mode Vista

Tags: windows-vista, wake-on-lan

If I put my computer to sleep I can wake it up remotely for the first few minutes. However if I let it sleep for an hour or so I cannot wake it unless I type on the keyboard. Any idea how I can configure the computer to behave the same regardless of how long it has been sleeping?

Answer (score 2):

Your network card may be set to sleep after a certain amount of time once the computer goes idle.You may want to check the power management options for it in the device manager to see if it's set to sleep.